# URL rewrite after dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, php

I need a solution for selecting after date and time
My LinK: `site-detail-last7days.php?sitename=Sitename&date1=2016-06-013%2020:00:00.000`

I want to modify date and time after `&date1=` ... with a value from dropdown list.. something like that.

[image]

And after I will select ex: Last 7 Days  my browser will refresh in

```
site-detail-last7days.php?sitename=Sitename&date1=2016-06-06 00:00:00.000
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Consider rewriting it so it is easier to understand what you are trying to understand and what your problem is.

Comment: i didn't tried anything because i don't now how to. Good so: I have this link site-detail-last7days.php?sitename=Sitename&date1=2016-06-06 00:00:00.000,   and a dropdown list with values (3 values: yesterday, last 7 days and last 30 days), when i click on 1 value from the dropdown that value must go in url and refreshing page. So my url (linK) wil be: site-detail-last7days.php?sitename=Sitename&date1=last 7 days

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
             <select onchange="chgLink(this);" >
                  <option value="">Please select</option>
                  <option value="1">Last Hour </option>
                  <option value="4">Last 4 Hours </option>
                  <option value="24">Yesterday </option>
                  <option value="168">Last 7 Days </option>
                  <option value="720">Last 30 Days </option>
              </select>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
        function chgLink(h) {
        //alert(h.value);
        var d = new Date();
        var d2 = new Date();

        d2.setHours(d.getHours() - h.value);

        //alert(d2);

        var year = d2.getFullYear();
        var mth = d2.getMonth();
        var date = d2.getDate();
        var hrs = d2.getHours();
        var mins = d2.getMinutes();
        var secs = d2.getSeconds();
        var milisecs = d2.getMilliseconds();

        var newDate = year+"-"+mth+"-"+date+" "+hrs+":"+mins+":"+secs+"."+milisecs;
        //alert(newDate);

        var Sitename = "google.com";

        window.location.assign("site-detail-last7days.php?sitename="+Sitename+"&date1="+newDate);

    }
```

You will have to supply sitename and put the full URL in window.location.assign.
Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys, but I already solved. My method is:

```
<div class="bar-right-datetime">
            <?php echo  $date1; echo ' -- '.date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime("+1 hour", $last4hours)); ?>  </span>

                             <select id="hours">                      
                <option value="0">--Select Date And Time--</option>
                <option value="site-detail-last7days.php?sitename=<?php echo $row['site_name'] ?>&date1=<?php echo $last1hour; ?>">Last Hour </option>
                <option value="site-detail-last7days.php?sitename=<?php echo $row['site_name'] ?>&date1=<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime("-3 hours", $last4hours)); ?>">Last 4 Hours </option>
                <option value="site-detail-last7days.php?sitename=<?php echo $row['site_name'] ?>&date1=<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime("-7 hours", $last4hours)); ?>">Last 8 Hours </option>
                <option value="site-detail-last7days.php?sitename=<?php echo $row['site_name'] ?>&date1=<?php echo $last1day->format('Y-m-d H:i'); ?>">Last 24 Hours </option>
                <option value="site-detail-last7days.php?sitename=<?php echo $row['site_name'] ?>&date1=<?php echo $last7days->format('Y-m-d H:i'); ?>">Last 7 Days</option>
                <option value="site-detail-last7days.php?sitename=<?php echo $row['site_name'] ?>&date1=<?php echo $last14days->format('Y-m-d H:i'); ?>">Last 14 Days</option>
                <option value="site-detail-last7days.php?sitename=<?php echo $row['site_name'] ?>&date1=<?php echo $last1month->format('Y-m-d H:i'); ?>">Last 30 Days</option>
                <option value="site-detail-last7days.php?sitename=<?php echo $row['site_name'] ?>&date1=<?php echo $last3months->format('Y-m-d H:i'); ?>">Last 3 Months</option>
                <option value="site-detail-last7days.php?sitename=<?php echo $row['site_name'] ?>&date1=<?php echo $last12months->format('Y-m-d H:i'); ?>">Last 12 Months</option>
            </select>
<script>
document.getElementById("hours").onchange = function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
        window.location.href = this.value;
    }        
};
```

and I declared variables from echo with

```
    $last1hour = date('Y-m-d H:i');

$currenttime = date('Y-m-d H:i');


$last4hours = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i'));
$last8hours = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i'));  

$last1day = new DateTime('today');
$last1day->modify('-1 day');


$last7days = new DateTime('today');
$last7days->modify('-7 day');


$last14days = new DateTime('today');
$last14days->modify('-14 day');


$last1month = new DateTime('today');
$last1month->modify('-1 month');


$last3months = new DateTime('today');
$last3months->modify('-3 month');


$last12months = new DateTime('today');
$last12months->modify('-12 month');
```

THANKS A LOT AGAIN.